# Not able to see the Docker logo in Build History for a pipeline job

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Converted a jenkins job running in a docker container to a pipeline job. Although the job runs smoothly, I am not able to see the Docker logo in the Build History of the pipeline job which was the case for a normal free style job running on Docker.

All the stages of the pipeline are inside the Docker container so essentially, the entire job runs inside the container. So why isn't the Docker logo visible against each build in the Build History. There are Docker fingerprints available in each build.

Could someone suggest what I am missing here?